# What's the special red resource required to forge the Shard of Icarael?

Tags: endless-legend

I've got a quest in which I have to equip one of my heroes with the Shard of Icarael, but it requires a resource that I don't know about.  What is it ?

[image: The shard of Icarael]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Palladian, a new strategic resource that will unlock during the third era, along with Adamantian.

[image: Smelting station: Adamantian and Palladian extractors]

Glassteel and Titanium are not the only strategic resources of the game.  During the fourth era, you'll unlock two additional strategic resources: Mithrite and Hyperium.

[image: Rare metal foundry: Mithrite and Hyperium extractors]

All these resources will be necessary to build the latest gears you will unlock using research.